# payment integration in ucommerce umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

hello  i have created  a demo razore store from package files of avenue clothing but when i impliment payment gateways in this store paypal worked fine but when i create sage pay and authorize.net and choose pipeline checkout then the order is not completed and it shows the  Error loading MacroEngine script (file: uCommerce/Preview.cshtml) so i just want to ask whether something is missing or for authorize.net we have a credit card payment option but is not showing in our store and throws this error without completing order

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version of uCommerce 3 and the Razor Store. An update was released 11/19/2012 for the Razor store to address an issue similar to the one you're describing.

Grab the latest version from Bitbucket at https://bitbucket.org/uCommerce/ucommerce-razor-store/downloads